# C# and XNA rotate an object around another object keeping the offset (or HOW TO SKIN A RANDOM POINT AGAINS A RANDOM BONE)

Tags: c#, math, rotation, offset, quaternions

I have an object X, positioned in the World space, represented by its quaternion, lets call the latter X_Base.
I have another object Y, offset from object X and presented by its quaternion matrix called Y_Base.

That's their positions at time zero, at time 1 they change their positions. Object Y rotates around it's axis for some angle and I know it's new quaternion it is Y_New. X is rotated relatively to Y so to keep the offset held at time 0. What I need is basically X_New.

In English, I am trying to manually skin a model. I have a mesh that is offset from the bone for some distance and I need it to keep this offset when the bone rotates. Somewhy I can't find a clear answer as to what formula I need to use.

Would be grateful for any advise.

A bit more clarification:

imagine a solar system, Earth rotates around the Sun and around it's axis. Let's put it so that Moon does not rotate around Earth but it is offset from Earth and keeps the offset no matter how you transform Earth's position. What I need is to find out where the Moon rests at time1, while knowing where it was at time0 and where Earth was at time0 and is at time1.

Comment: Can you not just simply multiply the quaternions together to place object x in object y's frame of reference?

Comment: I can't clearly understand what you mean. I will try to explain what I need: imagine a solar system, Earth rotates around the Sun and around it's axis. Let's put it so that Moon does not rotate around Earth but it is offset from Earth and keeps the offset no matter how you transform Earth's position. What I need is to find out where the Moon rests at time1, while knowing where it was at time0 and where Earth was at time0 and is at time1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to skin my model. Here is what I did:

1. "Sun" is my model's bone. It can translate (in world space) and rotate. "Earth" is a custom point on a model that moves rotated/translated with the model as my goal implies that I can't just pick any point and skin it, I need the latter to move with the model.
2. I have two methods in my app: one that launches once (Initialize) and another one that launches every frame (Update). In Initialize method my model is always at T-Pose.
3. In Initialize method I read the position of the Sun and Earth as 2 `XNA Matrix`.
4. In Initialize I also compute

   ```
   Vector3 Difference = TPoseEarth.Translation - TPoseSun.Translation;
   ```
5. Finally in Initialize I decompose Sun's Matrix to gain pure Sun's rotation matrix (without translation). I do so because my model's bone Sun apparently has a non-identity matrix assigned to it even at T-Pose. like so:

   ```
   Vector3 scale;
   Quaternion rotation;
   Vector3 tra;
   TPoseSun.Decompose(out scale, out rotation, out tra);

   BaseSunRot = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(rotation);
   ```
6. In Update method I get the current World position of Earth and Sun. I decompose the Sun's Matrix to get the pure rotation (again!).

   ```
   Vector3 scale;
   Quaternion rotation;
   Vector3 tra;
   Sun.Decompose(out scale, out rotation, out tra);

   Matrix SunRot = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(rotation);
   ```
7. I compute the unique bone-Sun rotation by multiplying the inverse of my base rotation by my new rotation:

   ```
   Matrix UniqueRot = Matrix.Invert(BaseSunRot) * SunRot;
   ```
8. I set my Earth's Translation equal to the Difference (Between Sun's T-Pose position and Earth's T-Pose position):

   ```
   Matrix Earth = Matrix.Identity;
   Earth.Translation = Difference;
   ```
9. I multiply Earth matrix by the unique bone's (Sun's) rotation:

   ```
   Earth *= UniqueRot;
   ```
10. I add Sun's CURRENT position to provide for possible translations between frames:

    ```
    Earth += Sun.Translation;
    ```
11. The End. Earth matrix contains all the necessary info about the skinned vertex.

I am not 100% sure but I feel like this is basically a manual on how to skin ANY given point agains ANY bone in the world (i.e rotate/translate keeping the initial offset). The problem is, the code is not optimized :). If anyone have any ideas on how to optimize it I would HUGELY appreciate it.

Especially I want to know if I can skip the double matrix decomposition and simply multiply the full ScaleRotationTranslation matrices? I am trying it but without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You might have lost me at "quaternion", but I've seen many 2D examples of this issue and there's always a simple way around it:

Basically, you need to use the exact same `origin` and `rotation` for both objects so they will automatically keep a constant offset between them.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I think you will find this problem a lot more straight forward if you use matrices rather than quaternions.  A quaternion contains only rotation so you will need to store translation (position) separately in a vector whereas matrices contain both rotation and translation.

For a solar system, you would assign a world matrix to both the Sun and the Earth.  The sun is positioned so that it's centre is at the world origin [0,0,0].  The Sun's matrix will contain its rotation around the y axis (making it turn).

```
sun.World = Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle);
```

The Earth will have a position relative to the Sun.  This value will remain constant and is used to create a translation matrix.  If you then multiply this matrix with the Sun's world matrix you will get the Earth's world matrix:

```
earth.World =
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(earth.Position) *
    sun.World;
```

Note the order of matrix multiplication is important.  This will rotate the Earth's position around the Sun over time.  A rotation can also be applied to the Earth making it spin on its axis, like so:

```
earth.World =
    Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle) *
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(earth.Position) *
    sun.World;
```

To position the moon in orbit around the Earth, the same prinicpal can be applied:

```
moon.World =
    Matrix.CreateTranslation(moon.Position) *
    earth.World;
```

If you need to use Quaternions, you can convert them to and from matrices:

```
Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.CreateFromRotationMatrix(matrix);
Vector3 translation = matrix.Translation;

Matrix matrix = Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(quaternion);
matrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(translation) * matrix;
```

Comment: Wow looks like I completely misunderstood what I was using. I AM using the Matrix class in c#, I only thought they are quaternions because they are 4x4 matrices. Looks like I need to read about quaternions a lot more than I did :). In any case I will try your code right now.

Comment: Ok had no time to test this before now. This is what I did: I have access to the Sun's matrix and to the Earth's matrix at time0. So at time0 (once per game in the Initialize method) I computed the difference between these two matrices, precisely I subtract the Sun's matrix from the Earth one to get Diff matrix. Then I extract the relative position of the Earth from this matrix by doing "Vector3 EPos = Diff.Translation; Then every frame I do the following: Recompute the Sun's World position as a Matrix SunNew and build the new Earth's position as(see next comment)

Comment: Earth.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(EPos)*SunNew; The trick works, but the relative position of the Earth gets displaced. It must be positioned in the upper corner of the cube, but ends up in the lower part I will post a picture in a second.

Comment: http://piccy.info/view3/4852901/a8e3d6b0706b362c6cce9690d0cb3856/1200/     Be sure than when the object gets animated the cube stays in place. I tried to compute Diff in different ways but for no result.

Comment: This yielded the same result:   Earth.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(Vector3.Transform(EPos, New));

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but ideally you should position the Sun and the Earth so that the centre of each is at 0,0,0. The Earth's translation will be the distance from the centre of the Sun to the centre of the Earth. If you cannot edit the geometry, you could reposition the Earth origin by applying two translation matrices. One to position the centre of the Earth at 0,0,0 and a second which positions the Earth relative to the Sun. The important thing is the order of multiplcation of the two translation matrices and the Sun matrix.